# Applying for a maître de conférence position in applied math (section 26) - is there an in person audition?

Tags: application, professorship, faculty-application, assistant-professor, france

I am curious about the French academic system, specifically when one is applying for a maître de conférence position in section 26 (applied mathematics). My main question is: after gaining qualification and submitting your application for an mcf position at university X through the CNU/galaxie system, is there an in person audition at university X as well? When do these usually take place?

For instance, this year the synchronized applications will close at the end of March. The decisions will be released at the end of June. So, between the end of March and June, presumably applicants to university X will have to travel to university X to give a short talk? What if you apply to many schools - will you be expected to travel to all of the universities?

Comment: Just for our general education, can you provide a link, preferably to a site in English, that defines the position you are asking about? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of such a site to be honest. The position is the equivalent of tenure track assistant professor in the USA except people in this position get a decision about whether or not they will be tenured much sooner (usually after ~1-2 years).

Comment: Good enough. Thanks. And good luck, assuming you are the candidate.

Comment: @Buffy Don't you have access to Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ma%C3%AEtre_de_conf%C3%A9rences&redirect=no

Comment: @N.I., I know I'd be no help for many reasons. I just wanted clarification. I'm surprised it is on US wikipedia, actually. Always trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a two step process. You apply on Galaxy, and once the system closes, a first selection is made exclusively on the basis of the application files: just a few candidates will be auditioned. You must attend auditions, and if you have been selected for auditions by several universities, you can either chose to decline an audition, or you can try to attend several of them even if you have to be at one location in the morning and another later that day.
If you decline an audition, you will no longer be considered for that position.

Comment: Is there any way to know when the audition will be for a given university in advance? Imagine you have some commitment already in May, you would want to ensure that there were no audition dates at this time or at least know in advance to move things around.

Comment: @j.kookalinski The closest thing to an official source of information is Opération Postes: http://postes.smai.emath.fr/2022/CONCOURS/liste_postes.php?nature=MCF&section=26 (username "postes", password "p2022"). Look for "Dates CSE" > "Déroulement des auditions". Most of them are not yet known. It's unfortunate but if you are seriously considering an application for an MCF position, you should act as if the whole month of May is booked. There are 100+ applicants for any position, and the committees aren't going to make arrangements for anyone.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input @N.I. . I knew of that website but you've made it clearer where to look.

Comment: @N.I. I am having trouble understanding what some of the dates in that table mean. Do you know what the date for commission audition is?

Comment: @j.kookalinski There are 59 job openings listed in the link I gave you. Which one are you talking about? For each job, the committee meets twice: once to decide who gets interviewed (usually late March or April), and once to actually interview the people (May). Sometimes they decide on the same day on who to hire, and sometimes they meet a third time (typically, the next day). So if you see two or three dates in increasing order in the page "Dates CSE", they're that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to ask if you knew the date for a particular job opening; I meant to ask if you knew what is meant by the dates in the column for commission auditions. Based on your response, I guess the commission audition date is when the committee meets in late March/April to decide who gets through to the next stage (interviewing in May)?

Comment: @j.kookalinski In the first meeting, they decide who gets to the next stage based on the submitted applications. The candidates don't come to that. Usually they write the list of selected candidates on Opération Postes the same day, and the official notification comes a few days later through Galaxie. In the second meeting, they actually interview the candidates. In normal times, the candidates have to physically come to the university for that. With COVID some interviews have moved online.